# Error : Cannot find Module 'cors' in fabric 1.2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, hyperledger, npm-install

I was getting Error: Cannot find module 'fabric-client'error then manually I ran 'npm install fabric-client@1.0.5' inside node_module then I am getting below error

```
[root@ip-172-31-61-27 controller]# node app.js module.js:538
        throw err;
        ^
    Error: Cannot find module 'cors'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/AWSNodeApp/controller/app.js:27:11)
        at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
```

We already have an entry of 'cors' in the package.json file but still it given above error.
Below is the package.json file :-

```
{
  "name": "awsnodeapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.538.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.3",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.2",
    "fabric-ca-client": "1.3.0",
    "fabric-client": "1.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "^2.0.0",
    "log4js": "^3.0.6",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "ws": "^6.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please give more context to the problem you're having

Answer (score 2):

Since your `app.js` requires `cors` module, you need to install and add to `package.json`.

```
npm install cors --save
```

You can find the answer from this old post: [Error: Cannot find module 'cors'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47706022/error-cannot-find-module-cors)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I have already tried the solution has been given in the link, but no luck.
Please refer package.json file and let me know any issue in that file.